# sethours updating time part but not the date part in date time field

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I've a datetime field with date only as format. Also, I've added a script at onload so that whenever a record is accessed `12:00` should be added to that field. It works as expected and add 12 hours to the time part. But it do not update the date accordingly.

For example, I've Date Become Manager field and its value is `'Thu Apr 30 23:00:00 UTC-1200 1992'`. And after adding 12 hours it updates the time part as `'Thu Apr 30 12:00:00 UTC-1200 1992'` but do not add anything to its date. Following is my snippet for this to update.

```
    function updateFields(field){
    var dateField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(field);
    if(dateField.getValue()== null)
    {
        dateField.setValue(new Date());
    }
    dateField.setValue(dateField.getValue().setHours(12, 0, 0));
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong in it.

Answer (score 2):

`setHours` only *changes* the time, it doesn't compute anything.

The most common way to perform this kind of computation is this:

```
var numberOfHours = 12; // how many hours you want to add. Can be *negative* too.
var millisecondsInAnHour = 60 * 60 * 1000; // this is constant
var offset = numberOfHours * millisecondsInAnHour;
var newFieldValue = dateField.getValue().getTime() + offset;
dateField.setValue(newFieldValue);
```

Basically, you grab the time of the value and add/subtract a number of milliseconds to it.

Answer (score 1):

So to be clear, you want to add 12 hours to the current date value, (as opposed to just setting time element to 12:00)?

`setHours` just sets the time, it doesn't add 12 hours to the time. If you do it multiple times it will always be 12 hours, rather than 0 - 12 - 24.

If you combine `setHours` with `getHours` you should be able to achieve the desired behaviour.

```
var d1 = new Date();
console.log("Original Date: " + d1);
d1.setHours(12);
console.log("Set 12 Hours Once: " + d1);
d1.setHours(12);
console.log("Set 12 Hours Twice: " + d1);

var d2 = new Date();
console.log("Original Date 2: " + d2);
d2.setHours(d2.getHours() + 12);
console.log("Add 12 Hours Once: " + d2);
d2.setHours(d2.getHours() + 12);
console.log("Add 12 Hours Twice: " + d2);
```

Output:

```
Original Date: Tue Sep 22 2015 09:45:39 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
Set 12 Hours Once: Tue Sep 22 2015 12:45:39 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
Set 12 Hours Twice: Tue Sep 22 2015 12:45:39 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
Original Date 2: Tue Sep 22 2015 09:45:39 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
Add 12 Hours Once: Tue Sep 22 2015 21:45:39 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
Add 12 Hours Twice: Wed Sep 23 2015 09:45:39 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just updated my code and it works. Please have a look into following code snippet.

```
function updateFields(field){
var dateField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(field);
if(dateField.getValue()== null)
{
    dateField.setValue(new Date());
}
dateField.setValue(dateField.getValue().setHours(dateField.getValue().getHours() + 12));}
```